# why the text path are not rendered?

Tags: svg

I really got puzzled why these two text are not displayed along the line and path. Could someone point me out?

```html
  <svg width="300px" height="300px">
    <line id="ok" x1="10" y1="20" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="red" stroke-width=10>
      <text>
        <textPath stroke="black" xlink:href="#ok">OHHHHSUHDIAU</textPath>
      </text>
    </line>
    <path id="io" d="M10,10 L100,10" stroke="blue" stroke-width=10>
      <text>
        <textPath stroke="black" xlink:href="#io">io</textPath>
      </text>
    </path>
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can only do a `<textPath>` on a `<path>`

placing the `<text>` inside the `<line>` or `<path>` elements were causing them not to be rendered.

here is my best guess at what you're trying to accomplish, I hope this helps

```html
<svg width="300px" height="300px">
  <defs>
    <path id="io" d="M10,10 L100,10" />
    <path id="ok" d="M10,20 L100,100" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#io" stroke-width="10" stroke="blue" />
  <use xlink:href="#ok" stroke-width="10" stroke="red" />
  <text>
    <textPath stroke="black" xlink:href="#io">io</textPath>
    <textPath stroke="black" xlink:href="#ok">OHHHHSUHDIAU</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```